# Can we insert into external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, tez

I am debugging a Big Data code in Production environment of my company. Hive return the following error:

```
Exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.LockException: No record of lock  could be found, may have timed out
Killing DAG...
Execution has failed.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. 
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:282)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:392)
    at HiveExec.main(HiveExec.java:159)
```

After investigation, I have found that this error could be caused by BoneCP in connectionPoolingType property, but the cluster support team told me that they fixed this bug by upgrading BoneCP.

My question is: can we INSERT INTO an **external table** in Hive, because I have doubt about the insertion script ?

Comment: Is this a question about an Oracle External Table?

Comment: no, about Hive external tables

Comment: Removing the oracle tag then.

Comment: Are you using Oracle as your  metastore?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can insert into external table.

Comment: Please try to use - `set datanucleus.connectionPoolingType=dbcp;` before running the insert